# Email Services : Short Email Alias

Tags: apex, email

I have created a custom email service class for creating custom object records from email requests.

The salesforce generated email address (shown below)

a) Is quite long..like 100 chrs "a23a3de3dq21e1xqw" etc

b) Is not meaningful obviously

Can someone tell me how to abbreviate this long email address to short email address ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way would be to have your mailserver guys create an alias address like 'sfcontent@yourdomain.com' that is simply a forwarding address to the real SF email service address.  That way it's human readable and users don't need to care about the SF part.

I'm presuming that users will be able to send mail to this address and create a record in SF based upon the email content.

Comment: Thanks...that will work for Corp settings...is there anything that can be done for developer edition ?

Comment: There is no SF-provided way to shorten the email address. It is intentionally long and meaningless to help prevent spamming of these addresses. You could get a free email address from gmail, outlook.com, yahoo, etc., and configure it to forward. You can use a free forwarding-only service like 33mail.com. Many low-cost domain registrars include free forwarding services for addresses in your domain, eg, namecheap.com or gandi.net.